# Delete object from list database Entity

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, list

I have a problem with deleting an objet from a list in a object in a database.

Here is my class :

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    private List<Project> projects;
    public virtual List<Projet> Projects
    {
        get { return projects; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                projects = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the context :

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Projet> Projects {get; set;}
}
```

But when in my dal, I try to do this :

```
public void ClientDeleteProject(Client c, Project p)
{
    c.Projects.Remove(p);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Well, the list still contains the project p. I even tried to do a RemoveAll(pr => pr.Id == p.Id), also I tried to directly delee the project in the database with db.Projects.Remove(p) but still, nothing happens.
I tried also to empty the list by doing a new List() by nothing happens too ...

What am I missing ? Whether I work with the object or its Id, the "projects" list af Client does not change ...

Thank you for your help !

Edit :

Here is some more concrete code :

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string name;
    private string address;
    private string image;
    private List<Contact> contactsClient;
    private List<Project> projectsClient;
    //properties are defined after that, with the keyword "virtual" for the lists
}
```

Actually my problem is for another class but it way easier to present with "Project", here is the class with the problem :

```
public class Contact : Person
{
    private Client associatedClient;
    private List<Projet> i;
    private List<Projet> ir;
    //same for the properties
}
```

Person is just a class with multiple string such as first name, last name, ... with the associated properties.

I tried this but it does not work. The contact is still in the database ...

```
Contact c = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(co => co.Id == id);
if( c != null) {
    db.Contacts.Remove(c);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I hope that helps.

Could it come from the fact my classes are not POCO ?

Comment: Why are you trying to delete something in memory (from your list) and then call SaveChanges on db ? It makes no sense ... If you want to delete it from Db, you should use your DbSet of projects to delete it. Else, this is nothing to do in your DAL.... Have you set a breakpoint to see if your list is filled ?

Comment: Please, do the correct thing, USE a variable of the same type of Project, What I mean is "not use Contact c" but "Project p = db.Project...". After execute remove using returned variables. Do you know that entity framework will use your object to understand what table refer for deletion?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake : I meant `db.Contacts.Remove` in the last snippet.

Comment: Could it come from that the fact that my classes are not POCO ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.
To delete data you have to use the DbContext object, this is the real connector between your data and the database.

The correct way is like this:

```
var project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
if( project != null) {
    db.Projects.Remove(project);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The other object is not related to anything. I use "FirstOrdefault" with match by Id because I don't know if your object (the project) is attached to the context.

Comment: There is no "RemoveAll" method in a DbSet, am I wrong ?

Comment: Ops, I made an error. Please check my edited answer :)

Comment: May throw an exception if FirstOrDefault returns null

Comment: For some reason, my project is not deleted from the database. When I query my database after this, I can still see it ...

Comment: Is there a possibility that I can't delete an object because it is referenced in another table or something like that ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm late. Anyway NO, is not possible. SaveChanges will always throw an exception of something goes wrong, can you provide as at least one example in which your code is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

You're not deleting anything from database.

You should remove from context in order to persist your changes 
Assuming that the p you're passing is a valid instance retrieve from Db with EF

```
db.Projects.Remove(p);
db.SaveChanges();
```

if not, you'll have to do this

```
var project = db.Project.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == p.Id);
if(project != null) {
   db.Projects.Remove(project);
   db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the object first by its id then after delete that object

```
if( db.Projects.Find(id) != null) {
    db.Projects.Remove(project);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```